# Thread Error needs to be found

Tags: java, android

I am placing a code below, I have created a local Thread and getting Error at the last Closing Braces, Can anybody please sort it out for me.

```
Thread dt = new Thread(this){
public void run() 
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        GetCurrentLocation loc = new GetCurrentLocation(RestaurantFinder.this);
        loc.setLocParams();

        int counter = 0;
        String lat = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLatitude();
        String lon = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLongitude();

        while (lat == null && lon == null
                && counter <= 1000) 
        {
            lat = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLatitude();
            lon = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLongitude();
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("The Latitude are:" + lat);
        System.out.println("The Longitude are:"+ lon);

        if (lat == null && lon == null) 
    {
            // another alert for location not found

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(RestaurantFinder.this);
            builder1.setTitle("Restaurant Finder");
            builder1.setMessage("Unable to find the Current Location");
            builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                                {


                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog1 = builder1.create();
            dialog1.show();

            // dismiss ProgressDialog by Handler
            pd.dismiss();

        } 
        else
        {

            weather();
            // dismiss ProgressDialog by Handler
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }

});<--(Error:Syntax error on token ")", Delete this token)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you indented your code properly, problems like this would be much easier to spot.

If I've matched the braces correctly, I think that the immediate problem (the syntax error) should be fixed by simply deleting the `)` character.

However, there is something really suspicious about the `this` argument in the anonymous thread class instantiation:

1. If you want to pass an argument like that, you need a corresponding constructor in you anonymous inner class.
2. It looks like `this` might be an instance of `Runnable`.  If so, then overriding the `run` method of `Thread` defeats the purpose of passing a `Runnable` via the constructor.
3. Subclassing the `Thread` class is generally thought to be a bad idea.

I think your code ought to look like this:

```
Thread dt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         ...
     }
});
```

... which might explain why you had the extra `)` in there in the first place!!

Or if `this` really is a `Runnable` you could write:

```
Thread dt = new Thread(this);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen C, I sorted it out by referring your answer. It was that "this" which was putting me in slough. It is all correct now.

Answer (score 1):

LOL... as the error says: **Delete this token)** , so do it this way:

```
Thread dt = new Thread(this){
public void run() 
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        GetCurrentLocation loc = new GetCurrentLocation(RestaurantFinder.this);
        loc.setLocParams();

        int counter = 0;
        String lat = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLatitude();
        String lon = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLongitude();

        while (lat == null && lon == null
                && counter <= 1000) 
        {
            lat = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLatitude();
            lon = GetCurrentLocation.getCurrentLongitude();
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("The Latitude are:" + lat);
        System.out.println("The Longitude are:"+ lon);

        if (lat == null && lon == null) 
    {
            // another alert for location not found

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(RestaurantFinder.this);
            builder1.setTitle("Restaurant Finder");
            builder1.setMessage("Unable to find the Current Location");
            builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                                {


                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog1 = builder1.create();
            dialog1.show();

            // dismiss ProgressDialog by Handler
            pd.dismiss();

        } 
        else
        {

            weather();
            // dismiss ProgressDialog by Handler
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
};
```